# What scripting language can I use to automate a concatenation & zipping process?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, zip, merge, bash-script

For a project I'm doing I need to concatenate and compress (with zip) many (midi) files and compare their sizes. I've thought there must be some language that allows me to do something like this:

1. create all pairwise concatenations (i.e. I need to merge files 01.mid and 02.mid and create file 0102.*, I don't care if it's a valid midi file or not, I just want it to have the information of both of them. Is .tar a good option?)
2. compress all files independently (original and concatenated)
3. check all file sizes and write them in some table which I can then import with Matlab or something

Should I use bash scripting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bash scripting, but for compression etc. it relies on other programs. You might be better of with Python, or any other scripting language which can generate CSV files  for you (although CSV syntax is not necessarily difficult to generate), and that can do the concatenation and compression.

Given this directory of files (all different length, but filled with the same character):

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users   24 Apr 16 15:03 01.mid
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users  254 Apr 16 15:03 02.mid
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users  455 Apr 16 15:03 03.mid
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users   98 Apr 16 15:03 04.mid
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users  444 Apr 16 15:03 05.mid
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users  239 Apr 16 15:03 06.mid
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users  257 Apr 16 15:03 07.mid
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users  128 Apr 16 15:03 08.mid
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users  228 Apr 16 15:03 09.mid
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users  160 Apr 16 15:03 10.mid
```

and this program `test.py`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import sys
import os
import csv
import bz2

comb_name_map = {}
file_names = []
prev_name = None

# combine the names
for name in sys.argv[1:]:
    if prev_name:
        basename, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
        basename = os.path.basename(basename)
        combi_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(prev_name))[0] + name
        comb_name_map[combi_name] = (prev_name, name)
        prev_name = None
    else:
        prev_name = name

for combi, org in comb_name_map.iteritems():
    file_names.append(combi + '.bz2')
    with bz2.BZ2File(file_names[-1], 'w') as outf:
        for name in org:
            with open(name, 'rb') as inf:
                buf = inf.read()
                outf.write(buf)
                file_names.append(name + '.bz2')
                with bz2.BZ2File(file_names[-1], 'w') as compf:
                    compf.write(buf)

with open('filesizes.csv', 'w') as fp:
    csvf = csv.writer(fp)
    for name in file_names:
        size = os.path.getsize(name)
        csvf.writerow([name, size])
```

run as:

```
python test.py *.mid
```

You will get the following output files:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 45 Apr 16 15:26 0102.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 39 Apr 16 15:26 01.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 39 Apr 16 15:26 02.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 45 Apr 16 15:26 0304.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 43 Apr 16 15:26 03.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 39 Apr 16 15:26 04.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 44 Apr 16 15:26 0506.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 43 Apr 16 15:26 05.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 39 Apr 16 15:26 06.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 41 Apr 16 15:26 0708.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 39 Apr 16 15:26 07.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 37 Apr 16 15:26 08.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 43 Apr 16 15:26 0910.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 39 Apr 16 15:26 09.mid.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 anthon users 39 Apr 16 15:26 10.mid.bz2
```

and a file `filesizes.csv`:

```
0910.mid.bz2,43
09.mid.bz2,39
10.mid.bz2,39
0708.mid.bz2,41
07.mid.bz2,39
08.mid.bz2,37
0304.mid.bz2,45
03.mid.bz2,43
04.mid.bz2,39
0506.mid.bz2,44
05.mid.bz2,43
06.mid.bz2,39
0102.mid.bz2,45
01.mid.bz2,39
02.mid.bz2,39
```

Make sure you have an even number of `.mid` files. To include the original filenames and sizes, just concatenate the name to `file_names` while processing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - bash scripting will be able to meet the requirements. But you should use whatever scripting language you are comfortable with. python, perl are other possibilities.

Comment: A further advantage of perl or python (or ruby) would be that these should all have libraries for interfacing with matlab, and much better data structures than bash for tables.